# Inheritance mapping in beego?

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, orm, beego

What is the inheritance mapping in beego like hibernate ?
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html

There is no documentation in beego doc(http://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/orm.md).

classes like this:

Student extends Person

Teacher extends Person

Answer (score 2):

I think beego orm doesn't support yet. https://github.com/astaxie/beego/issues/1389 this is simpler issue.

Answer (score 1):

Beego ORM doesn't support yet. If you really need it. you can try GORM http://jinzhu.me/gorm/ .

Answer (score 0):

```html
There is no features like this yet there is an alternative solution
where you can import your controller into another controller.
ex - In ControllerA
type ControllerA struct {
 ControllerB
}
func (this *ControllerA) Test() {
    res := this.DoSomething("Asdasd")
    fmt.Println(res)
}

In Controller B
type ControllerB struct {
 beego.Controller
}
func (this *ControllerB) DoSomething(name string) string{
    return name
}
```